# Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-admin, json

[image]

I am using wordpress 5.4.2. I get this error when trying to add a new post. I changed my permalink to

Post name sample

```
http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post/
```

How should i change my .htaccess

My current htaccess is

```
    # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress
```

~
Please help me II am new to wordpress

Akismet Anti-Spam Classic Editor Hello Dolly Increase Maximum Upload File Size Jetpack by WordPress.com myStickymenu OptinMonster API UberMenu 3 - The Ultimate WordPress Mega Menu .These are my installed plugins

This is my custom css

```css
    .site-info { 
        display: none; 
    }
    
    .entry-meta .byline, .entry-meta .cat-links { display: none; }
    
    .entry-meta .posted-on { display: none; }
    .entry-footer{
        display:none;
    }
    
    .postmetadata {display:none;}
    
    .entry-meta {display:none !important;}
        .home .entry-meta { display: none; }
        .entry-footer {display:none !important;}
        .home .entry-footer { display: none; }
```

Console error

```
    [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #_wpnonce: (More info: https:// goo.gl/9p2vKq) <input type=​"hidden" id=​"_wpnonce" name=​"_wpnonce" value=​"65e17e3128">​ <input type=​"hidden" id=​"_wpnonce" name=​"_wpnonce" value=​"2ba7a6de71">​
    /wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    data.min.js?ver=e80048e7b309581a40e44b8bd8aaba41:2 Uncaught (in promise) Objectcode: "invalid_json"message: "The response is not a valid JSON response."__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need to change your htaccess. Have you made any other changes recently. New plug-in? Theme? Custom code?

Comment: no .I havent added any plugins i just changed the permalink to new post

Comment: can you please tell me  how to change the .htaccess

Comment: I told you, you don’t need to. That’s not your problem.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie Akismet Anti-Spam Classic Editor Hello Dolly Increase Maximum Upload File Size Jetpack by WordPress.com myStickymenu OptinMonster API UberMenu 3 - The Ultimate WordPress Mega Menu .These are my installed plugins

Comment: That htaccess looks wrong. Did you edit it already? Is it in the /wordpress directory, or striaght in the root?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I disabled all plugins and still getting the same error .I think it is not the problem with plugins

Comment: @mozboz. I editted it

Comment: @mozboz can you please give the correct .htaccess

Comment: @mozboz It is in the wordpress directory

Comment: Sorry no I'm wrong, that .htaccess is correct if you installed at /wordpress . Is there anything else in your .htaccess file? Or do you have another one in the root directory?

Comment: @mozboz The problem started only after i changed the permalink to posname

Comment: Did you try putting the permalink back to see if that fixes it ;-) ? What does your permalink setting look like?

Comment: @mozboz If  i change the permalink back to  Plain it works ,For other options it is  not working

Comment: Deactivate all of your plugins. If the problem goes away (which it probably will) then re-activate each one of the plugins until you find the one that is causing the issue. If you get this problem with all Plugins deactivated, thats a lot more curious...

Comment: @t2pe I editted custom css.And does that have to do something with gutenberg editor

Comment: @t2pe. Can you please look at the console error that i have included above

Comment: @somanraj I edited out the pastebin link and put the result in the question, don't link offsite, embed the info directly in the question. In the meantime, the error message makes it clear what the problem is, 2 HTML tags with the same `id` value. It also looks like you have JS that calls a REST API endpoint that doesn't exist, or, you haven't saved permalinks since the endpoint was added. Unfortunately your dev console isn't wide enough to display the full URL of those endpoints so I cannot tell which it is. Also turn off all plugins and turn them on 1 by 1 to identify the culprit

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of guides around on how to resolve this. [Here](https://wpdexigner.com/response-is-not-a-valid-json-response/) is one example. In short, there's no one solution, this error can be caused by multiple issues that you all might have to address.

However, like for many others ([here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-failed-the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response-36/) are a few), these suggestions have not fixed the problem for me when I, on multiple occasions, encountered this problem, on multiple Wordpress installs.

The few times that I had to do a deep dive into what was actually the underlying cause, each time I found that it was a specific link, inside a paragraph which, when removed, made the problem go away.

Just today, I encountered this problem on a five year old Wordpress post. The post predated Gutenberg, and was using the Classic Editor. Converting to the Block Editor, or not, made no difference.

After combing through the post, I found that removing one single link resolved the problem. The link in question:

https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/docserver/eag-2017-en.pdf?expires=1523985351&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=5B06368AEE8D0E4FDC5531078FA481B1

Nothing really strange, as the link properly resolves. What I do notice, here, is that the link above resolves to a page, but not a pdf, as the link implies. On the page itself, the link that is provided to the document that is linked to is this:

https://read.oecd-ilibrary.org/education/education-at-a-glance-2017_eag-2017-en#page1

Replacing my offending link with the latter resolved the problem for me.

I've seen this before, a URL that seems fine, causing Wordpress to fail when trying to save a post. Perhaps this is your problem, too.

Update: I'm cleaning up old posts and found more links that resulted in posts failing to save. Several were links to PDFs, a few were Google Doc links, some were http, not https, and some were just plain links to newspaper websites.

I also found that having links set to open in new windows can result in this error, as does having anchors in the classic editor.

Answer (score -1):

I bet you are on a localhost server,  I had the same issue and fixed changing files permission. ALL wp-content files & folders,  and ALL wp-includes folder & files must have full permissions.

If you are on localhost this is not a problem, you could simply give full permission to the entire WP installation